# retrieving tweets from specific user older than 7 days

Tags: rest, twitter, tweets

i am trying to Get the tweets from any user ... but it returns only last 7 day's tweets... 
I want to retrieve tweets older than that... how to Do it.. .

Right now i am fetching tweets by

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from%3Amihirpmehta

this URL

but it only gives me tweets that are tweeted in last 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one... by using [MGTwitter](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa) i am able to retrieve it... Thanks

Comment: did you implement MGTwitter ?

Comment: No.. actually I`m doing in my grails app, using JTwitter, so i`d like to know how u did. and if JTwitter has that, or I have to implement something?!

Comment: i have implemented MGTwitter in my APP and it has that functionality... no idea about JTwitter....

Answer (score 1):

If you need collect Tweets older than 7 days you can't do it with Twitter's API, but I think you can do it using web-scraping (the tweets can easily be scraped with the Python module **BeautifulSoup** ; but please if any one know the disadvantage of this method tell us!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the twitter search API allows you to go back any further.  If you add the until parameter you can see that if you go back more than a week it returns a 404.