# Python twitter crawler for tweets older than one week?

Tags: twitter, web-crawler

For an academic usage, I would like to analyze about three months of tweets. However, it seems the [official Twitter search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) doesn't provide tweets older than one week.

I've tried to write a self crawler, however, given a search keyword, Twitter page will not show tweets older than about one week.

Is there any trick that I can get older tweets? Or my best bet is to hit the API once a week and do it for the following three months?

Comment: is it really the duration that is important, or are you just looking to obtain a certain volume of tweets?

Comment: @kmote volume is relatively easy. what I care is the duration.

Comment: You can crawl the search results of [Twitter Search](https://twitter.com/search-home). There are tweets that older than a week or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Twitter [API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) regarding limitations:

```
 - The Search API is not complete index of all Tweets, but instead an index of recent Tweets. 
 - At the moment that index includes between 6-9 days of Tweets.
 - You cannot use the Search API to find Tweets older than about a week.
```

So, yes, if you need to collect a certain span of time, it will require multiple queries, as you suggested.

(You should also read this answer: [retrieving tweets from specific user older than 7 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448203/retrieving-tweets-from-specific-user-older-than-7-days))

There are also currently two commercial companies that have access to the Twitter firehose and can provide this data (they are called "licensed re-syndicators"):

- [Gnip](http://gnip.com/) - offers 30 days of Twitter data
- [DataSift](http://datasift.com/) - up to two years of Twitter data